# How powershell handles returns from & calls

Tags: powershell

We have field devices that we decided to use a powershell script to help us handle 'updates' in the future. It runs every 5 minutes to execute `rsync` to see if it should download any new files. The script, if it sees any file types of .ps1, .exe, .bat ,etc. will then attempt to execute those files using the `&` operator. At the conclusion of execution, the script will write the file executed an excludes file (so that `rsync` will not download again) and remove the file. My problem is that the return from the executed code (called by `&`) behaves differently, depending on how the main script is called.

This is the main 'guts' of the script:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $ScriptDir\Installs\* -Include @("*.ps1","*.exe","*.cmd","*.VBS","*.MSI") | ForEach {

   Write-Verbose "Executing: $_"
   & $_
   $CommandName = Split-Path -Leaf $_
   Write-Verbose "Adding $CommandName to rsync excludes"
   Write-Output "$CommandName" | Out-File -FilePath $ScriptDir\excludes     -Append -Encoding ASCII
   Write-Verbose "Deleting '$_'"
   Remove-Item $_
}
```

When invoking powershell (`powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy bypass`) and then executing the script (`.\Update.ps1 -Verbose`), the script runs perfectly (*i.e.* the file is written to excludes and deleted) and you can see the verbose output (writing and deleting).

If you run the following (similar to task scheduler) `powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy bypass -NoProfile -File "C:\Update.ps1" -Verbose`, you can see the new script get executed but none of the steps afterwards will execute (*i.e.* no adding to excludes or removing the file or the verbose outputs).

Comment: My guess is that it might have to do with the way you are calling the `File` parameter.  In other words, the script expects all of calls to the files (executables, etc.) to be present either in the `pwd` (PowerShell working directory it was launched in) or, in the case of the explicit call, in the root `C` directory.

One of the changes I made to some of my scripts was to assign a variable to the `pwd`, and then append each call with that.

`Get-ChildItem` isn't returning any `Children` because `$ScriptDir` is different in either case.

Comment: gravity, appreciate the response. I guess I am a little confused. Are you talking about the file that is returned from Get-ChildItem? If so, that execution of it (for example, lets say we find script2.ps1) actually transpires, the difference in the way it operates is AFTER the execution of script2.ps1. In one case, it continues on with the loop and performs the remaining commands, in the other, it never make it to the Split-Path command. It acts like it 'dies' once script2.ps1 is executed.

Comment: This issue can be closed. I found out the script being called (not this one) had an exit statement which was causing powershell to terminate.

Comment: I believe you may request to close the question yourself.. it should be near the edit buttons above.